# Filtered Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

We have many filtered data extensions created in Marketing Cloud.  I need confirmation on retention period for FDE's for data protection rules.

Are there any rules applied on retention for filtered data extensions?

Comment: What makes you think retention rules apply to your filtered data extensions?

Comment: Exploring the unknowns, it was a questions submitted to me for a project I am working on.  If there are retention settings on the DE, would this subsequently remove the FDE one the period is up?

Comment: Have you tried the retention settings in the platform?

Comment: A filtered DE gets reloaded every time you refresh it so this retention thing doesn't make sense for this type of DE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules are based on your data retention policy.  Whether it's 6 months or indefinite.  However, if you have a filter and a DE that either has an ETL process or updates, then refresh your FDE and whether it is indefinite or 6-months, it won't go away.